# position:relative started working different than at first (asp.net)

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I was playing around with the code, testing things.. Everything was working good, but after I refreshed the page everything started working 'weird'

this is the code in admin.aspx:

```
<div id="LeftCenterPanel">
    <a href="#" id="Dashb" class="TableButtons">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#" id="Doct" class="TableButtons">Doctors</a>
</div>
```

and the css code for those:

```
#LeftCenterPanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
}

.TableButtons {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left:0;

   width: 100%;

   border-bottom: 1px solid #373e4a;
   text-decoration: none;     
}
    .TableButtons:hover{
        background-color: #373e4a;
       transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    }
```

at first. the Dashboard and Doctors button was under each other, max width.
Now they are next to each other, with the max width of the text.. even after I change the width to 200px it still stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **float:left** for a tags

```css
#LeftCenterPanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
}

.TableButtons {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
   float:left;
   width: 100%;

   border-bottom: 1px solid #373e4a;
   text-decoration: none;     
}
    .TableButtons:hover{
        background-color: #373e4a;
       transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    }
```

```html
<div id="LeftCenterPanel">
    <a href="#" id="Dashb" class="TableButtons">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#" id="Doct" class="TableButtons">Doctors</a>
</div>
```